# filter / generalize elevation points on the basis of some conditions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, elevation, generalization

I wanted to generalize many elevation points in a rectangular area (about 700 square km).  I need to take about 3 points for square km. These points must satisfy some conditions:
One of these conditions is to find the highest point in a buffer of 500m: I would loop on all the points / "raster cell" (I think vector analysis will be too heavy, so I thought to do a "raster approach" creating an elevation grid from points) and give a score of "5" to the highest points / "raster cell" 500m around each.
I wanted to do it in an ArcGIS ModelBuilder flow.

Comment: Another solution could be:
1) create a polygon feature buffering the points (buffer radius = 500m)
2) select the highest point inside each buffer
Is it possible? How could I do?
Thanks in advance!
Paolo

Answer (score 1):

The highest point within a 500 m radius is obtained by comparing its elevation to a 500 m circular neighborhood maximum based on the same elevation grid.  In pseudocode, this is

```
"elevation" >= FocalStatistics("elevation", NbrCircle(500, "MAP"), "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
```

The result is a boolean indicator grid whose `true` (1) cells designate such highest points.  This example covers a 5 by 6 km region, overlaying a hillshaded DEM (greens and yellow) with the result (in blue):

[image: Example map]

Comment: Thanks very much for your precious help, but, I'm sorry... I'm really a newbie with Phyton scripts. Could you please suggest me how to "use" the pseudocode? Just an input....
I suppose I've to use it in an Arcgis "field calculator". I copyed and pasted the pseudocode in the "expression field" of the field calculator but I receive and error.
Thanks in advance for all!
Paolo

Comment: You asked for a model, so just use Modelbuilder to (1) compute focal stats and (2) compare the original grid to it.

Comment: Thanks very much Whuber!
I put the focal statistics tool in a flow and it worked (ArcGis 10.0)! but...
the "focal statistics grid" I got is not a boolean indicator grid (with true (1) = cells with highest points) but another elevation grid with a cellsize = buffer size
(NbrCircle(500, "MAP") = 500m) and cell value = height value. I need the cellsize remains of the original size (5m), and cell value indicates me the highest pixel inside each single buffer.
I can't understand what's wrong...
Thanks in advance for your help!
Paolo

Comment: That's correct: the focal max returns maximum elevations. It seems you have forgotten to compare that to the original elevation grid: the comparison returns boolean values only.

Comment: Thank you very much Whuber... and I'm sorry to thank you so late!
It worked fine!
Thanks again!
Paolo

Comment: @Paolo You should mark this as the answer it sounds like.